# PYQGIS error in file format working in standalone script using PCharm

Tags: python, pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-processing

i want to run this PYQGIS python script in standalone out of QGIS and i use PyCharm Idle.
but my code have error on the file format.

the script

```
from qgis.core import *
import sys
import qgis.utils
from osgeo import ogr
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.gui import *

# supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)#for linux

# create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

# Write your code here to load some layers, use processing algorithms, etc.
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
import processing
Processing.initialize()
rasterlyr=QgsRasterLayer('/home/qgis2/PycharmProjects/test/aster.tif')
rasterlyr.isValid()
#slope='/home/qgis2/PycharmProjects/test/slope.tif'
#aspect='/home/qgis2/PycharmProjects/test/aspect.tif'
processing.runalg('saga:slopeaspectcurvature', rasterlyr,6,1,1,'/home/qgis2/PycharmProjects/test/slope.tif','/home/qgis2/PycharmProjects/test/aspect.tif',None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None)
#processing.alghelp("saga:slopeaspectcurvature")
# When your script is complete, call exitQgis() to remove the provider and
# layer registries from memory
qgs.exitQgis()
```

error message :

```
ERROR 4: `/tmp/processing969c81d9be194fa49b8dd2c0daebf68b/f9a3240b743f4554b2602e7940bf8fd2/SLOPE.sdat' not recognised as a supported file format.

*** Error in `/usr/bin/python2.7': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0af99d30 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
```

backtrace have many linux paths.